# group by issue in bigquery Standard sql and Unable to get unique record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

Getting error in group by " **Error: SELECT list expression references column id_coupon which is neither grouped nor aggregated at ...**"

*In my table " table_name " id_coupon has more than one entry for each id_discount. Means id_discount is not unique , id_coupon is unique  . I want to get only one id_coupon against each id_discount...*

```
SELECT
  id_discount,
  id_coupon
FROM
  abbccc.discounts.table_name
  GROUP BY id_discount
```

Comment: So if there are many id_discount for each id_coupon which id_discount would you like to return for each id_coupon? (min, max...?)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  id_discount,
  MIN(id_coupon) as id_coupon
FROM abbccc.discounts.table_name
GROUP BY id_discount
```